# Using replace in powershell script not replacing

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, powershell-4.0

Why replace is not working? Here is the code

```
$TestString = "<css>1</css><PredefinedValidator>9DE32F03C2734FFCB2D681FF6283FE88</PredefinedValidator><RegexPattern>^[\da-zA-Z\s+()\-']+$</RegexPattern><item>2</item>"
$NewString =  $TestString  -replace "<PredefinedValidator>9DE32F03C2734FFCB2D681FF6283FE88</PredefinedValidator><RegexPattern>^[\da-zA-Z\s+()\-']+$</RegexPattern>","<PredefinedValidator>9DE32F03C2734FFCB2D681FF6283FE88</PredefinedValidator><RegexPattern>^[0-9]+$</RegexPattern>"
write-host  $NewString
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is about making changes in an XML file, you shouldnýt use **textual** replace methods. There are many examples on how to do this, but if you show us the xml we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace operator will replace a string matching a regex pattern. From the looks of it, you are attempting to replace a literal string with another literal string and both of them happen to also have a regex pattern in them. Use the Replace method instead

```
$TestString = "<css>1</css><PredefinedValidator>9DE32F03C2734FFCB2D681FF6283FE88</PredefinedValidator><RegexPattern>^[\da-zA-Z\s+()\-']+$</RegexPattern><item>2</item>"
$NewString =  $TestString.Replace("<PredefinedValidator>9DE32F03C2734FFCB2D681FF6283FE88</PredefinedValidator><RegexPattern>^[\da-zA-Z\s+()\-']+$</RegexPattern>","<PredefinedValidator>9DE32F03C2734FFCB2D681FF6283FE88</PredefinedValidator><RegexPattern>^[0-9]+$</RegexPattern>")
write-host  $NewString
```